# Prevent automatic "step into" inside .min.js files in visual studio, while debugging

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, chrome-debugging

Is there any option like debug `Just my Code` on the line of C#, to prevent step into Javascript minified libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio, there is no option "Just my Code" for JavaScript code, but in the browser if you are using **F12 Developer tools**, and you'll find "Just my code" which could prevent the **Debugger tool** from stepping into a library code.

The official doc about
[Just my Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255007(v=vs.85)#just-my-code)